# Apache using up all memory with no visitors on website

Tags: php, apache, memory, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 13.04 server running Apache 2.22. When I restart apache, the web application is loaded quickly and everything works great. After about 5 minutes however, my entire 2GB is taken up. This happens even with no visitors on the site, no cron scripts running (other than system scripts). Its not showing what's using it all in top either. Any ideas?

```
root@replicator:/etc/apache2# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1994       1927         66          0         20         14
-/+ buffers/cache:       1892        102
Swap:         1953        696       1256
```

top

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                   
18750 www-data  20   0  272m  30m 4128 D   1.0  1.5   0:00.63 apache2                                                   
18748 www-data  20   0  269m  27m 4416 D   0.7  1.4   0:01.25 apache2                                                   
18752 www-data  20   0  265m  23m 4380 D   0.7  1.2   0:00.41 apache2                                                   
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:18.03 rcu_sched                                                 
  680 syslog    20   0  241m  216    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:16.32 rsyslogd                                                  
  925 root      20   0 21324  236  148 S   0.3  0.0   0:18.14 cron                                                      
18751 www-data  20   0  266m  25m 4204 D   0.3  1.3   0:00.26 apache2                                                   
18755 www-data  20   0  259m  18m 4388 D   0.3  0.9   0:00.41 apache2                                                   
18757 www-data  20   0  261m  19m 4152 D   0.3  1.0   0:00.15 apache2                                                   
    1 root      20   0 26664  780  180 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.67 init                                                      
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                  
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.48 ksoftirqd/0                                               
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0                                               
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                              
    6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u:0                                               
    7 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u:0H                                              
    8 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 migration/0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer over on Server Fault. This is definitely not a programming question.

https://serverfault.com/questions/408611/apache-httpd-process-utilizing-all-my-servers-memory